# Why would compiler give an error if a method get called cannot be found within the given glass since Objective-C checks it during runtime?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

For example, if I write `[self func]` but I don't have a func defined within self, then the compiler will give an error that no such method exists. But shouldn't Objective-C check this during runtime? Then why would compiler give an error just during compiling time?
I've googled but haven't found any answer that exactly answer my question.

Comment: Because it's just so handy to find errors in your code quickly without having to run the code.

Comment: But what if I'll add an implementation of `func` at runtime?

Comment: ARC decides what it needs to retain/release/autorelease based on the cocoa memory management conventions, which would suggest that knowing the selector's name is enough.